# why does std::getline fails after using operator>> twice?

Tags: c++, operators, getline, extract

I have the given input:

```
 local
 127.0.0.1 localhost
 other
 next
```

Using the following code the output is a blank where I expected **other**. The output is "output: "

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string ip, domain, header;
    std::getline(cin, header);
    cin >> ip >> domain;
    std::getline(cin, header);
    std::cout << "output: " << header;
}
```

However, I notice this problem occurs when extracting twice (`cin >> ip >> domain;`) before calling `std::getline`. The code works as I would expect if I had `cin >> ip`. Why am I seeing this weird result when I use double extraction(`operator>>`) with `std::getline`?

Comment: Are there blank lines in your input? Please format the post using code formatting to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream `operator>>` extracts whitespace which is *before* the data it extracts, not after. This means it extracts "localhost" into `domain`, but leaves following the newline in the stream. `getline()` then reads just this newline.

Comment: This is correct. When I use `std::getline(cin, header);` twice I get the correct result. Thanks.